# URL Regex for PHP framework

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the controller, method and queries from a URL array. Something like this:

'home/news/[day]/[month]/[slug]/'

I need some regex which will give me the following:

Controller: home
Method: News
Arguments: day, month, slug

For the arguments, it'd be nice if I could somehow get the name inside the brackets so I can put them into an associative array in PHP. e.g: ("day"=>$day).

I'm really stuck with this, and tried looking at several PHP frameworks for guidance but nothing really accomplishes exactly what I want above, especially using regex.

Comment: I think you should delegate the arguments thing to the "home" Controller or even the "news" method. That should not be the front controller's business. Apart from that, do you think it is a good idea to have a "home" controller?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, the home controller was just an example, in actual fact it'd likely be news/article/10/10/news-article-test/. 

Are you suggesting I just take all the queries and just pass the lot over to my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('{/home/news/(?<day>\d{1,2})/(?<month>\d{1,2})/(?<slug>[\w-]+)}',
           '/home/news/10/02/foo', 
           $matches);
```

`$matches` is now

```
array (
  0 => '/home/news/10/02/foo',
  'day' => '10',
  1 => '10',
  'month' => '02',
  2 => '02',
  'slug' => 'foo',
  3 => 'foo',
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're always going to have /:controller/:method/:args you might as well use explode:

```
$args = explode('/', $url);
$controllerName = array_shift($args);
$method = array_shift($args);

$controller = new $controllerName;
$response = $controller->$method($args);
```

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is I would like to route my URL first, as I may also want /:controller/:item_id or something. Thinking about it, I think the best way to do this would be a combination of both regex and then the method above. Thanks very much for your reply.